# Coq: Proving an application

Tags: function, definition, coq, proof

This is a bit theoretical question. We can define `fx` but seemingly not `fx'`:

```
Function fx {A} (x:A) (f:A->Type) (g:Type->f x): f x := g (f x).
Definition fx' {A} (x:A) (f:A->Type): f x.
```

In a way, this makes sense, as one cannot prove from the `f` and `x` that `f` has been (or will be) applied to `x`. But we can apply `f` to `x` to get something of type `Type`:

```
assert (h := f x).
```

This seems puzzling: one can apply `f` to `x` but *still* can't obtain a witness `y: f x` that he has done so.

The only explanation I can think of is this: as a type, `f x` is an application, as a term, it's just a type. We cannot infer a past application from a type; similarly, we cannot infer a future application from a function and its potential argument. As for (the instance of) applying itself, it isn't a stage in a proof, so we cannot have a witness of it. But I'm just guessing. The question:

**Is it possible to define `fx'`? If yes, how; if no, why (please give a theoretical explanation)**

Comment: `Function fx` is not really necessary here, `Definition fx` would work too.

Comment: Yes (I used both to show that both work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, a direct answer to your question: *no*, it is not possible to define `fx'`. According to your snippet, `fx'` should have type

```
forall (A : Type) (x : A) (f : A -> Type), f x.
```

It is not hard to see that the existence of `fx'` implies a contradiction, as the following script shows.

```
Section Contra.

Variable fx' : forall (A : Type) (x : A) (f : A -> Type), f x.

Lemma contra : False.
Proof.
  exact (fx' unit tt (fun x => False)).
Qed.

End Contra.
```

What happened here? The type of `fx'` says that for any family of types `f` indexed by a type `A`, we can produce an element of `f x`, where `x` is arbitrary. In particular, we can take `f` to be a constant family of types `(fun x => False)`, in which case `f x` is the same thing as `False`. (Note that `False`, besides being a member of `Prop`, is also a member of `Type`.)

Now, given your question, I think you are slightly confused by the meaning of types and propositions in Coq. You said:

> This seems puzzling: one can apply `f` to `x` but still can't obtain a
>   witness `y: f x` that he has done so.

The fact that we can apply `f` to `x` simply means that the expression `f x` has a valid type, which, in this case, is `Type`. In other words, Coq shows that `f x : Type`. But having a type is a different thing from being *inhabited*: when `f` and `x` are arbitrary, it is not possible to build a term `y` such that `y : f x`. In particular, we have `False : Type`, but there is no way we can build a term `p` with `p : False`, because that would mean that Coq's logic is inconsistent.